# X subset of space vector V, $Tv=Sv, v \in X$ then T=S

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given two linear transformations:$$S,T: V \to W$$
such that $X\subseteq V$, and it is true that $S(v)=T(v), \forall v\in X$, and the exercise requests to prove that $S=T$. I have started by writing the vectors in X $ \{v_{1},\ldots, v_m\} $ then relating them to each one of them to a vector in $W$, and I don't think this is the right way to approach the exercise. I'm not so sure what to do next and if you were able to give me any hints to continue this exercise it would be very helpful.

Comment: This is not true in general. For example, if $X = \{0\}$, then $Tv = Sv = 0$ for $v \in X$, which tells you nothing about what happens on $V \setminus X$. (All linear maps satisfy $Tv = 0$ if $v=0$.)

Comment: If there was an extra condition to make this true, which one should be? It is probable that they made a mistake when typing the exercise, but this was all the information given by the author.

Comment: @zastenAmir If $X$ is a basis of $V$ then this can be true.

Comment: I think it would be true if and only if the span of $X$ is all of $V$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, should I delete the post?

Comment: No need to delete, just accept whichever answer you prefer. Both show valid counterexamples.

Comment: One of those operator might be regular and the other wouldn't have to be.

Comment: @zastenAmir, is this the original statement? Usually things with counterexamples like the ones below come with a "prove or disprove" rather than "prove."

Comment: It is the original statement, but the counterexamples proved it to be wrong and that there was something missing in the statement made by the author. Should I change anything in the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily true.

Let $T=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $S=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $X=\{(x,y) \, | \, y=x\}$. Then both $S$ and $T$ agree on $X$ but they are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily true. Consider, $S,T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $S(x,y)= (x,y) $ and $T(x,y)=(x,-y)$ which are linear. 
Let, $X=\mathbb{R}×0$ on which S and T are same but they are not same on the whole space.